# не получается импортировать psutil в python

Tags: python

У меня появилась проблема. Когда я пытаюсь импортировать `psutil` в терминале *Python*, то пишет: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'`, не смотря на то, что я уже установил его через `pip`.

Команды:

`pip install psutil` - установил `psutil`

`import psutil` - после этого выдает ошибку

Comment: Убедитесь, что у вас версия питона, куда вы ставили `psutil` совпадает с версией питона, что запускает скрипт. Например, у вас в проекте может использовать virtual environment из-за этого возникло несколько версий